# Prove that a function is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ metric spaces and $U \subset X , V\subset Y$ open sets.
Let $f:U\rightarrow V$ be a homeomorphism. Prove that $f$ is an open map. I need to show that for every open subset of $U′⊂U$, $f(U′)$ is open.

This is a question from a multi-variable calculus class. I have tried first to assume $U$ as a open ball then playing with the inverse of $f$, but I'm clueless.

Comment: I have tried first to assume U as a open ball then playing with the inverse of $f$, but I'm clueless

Comment: Because $f$ is a homeomorphism, we know that $f^{-1}:V\rightarrow U$ is continuous, and hence that $(f^{-1})^{-1}[W]=f[W]$ is open for every open subset $W$ of $U$.

Comment: $f$ is not a homeomorphism of $X$ and $Y$, but of $U$ and $V$. I need to show that for every open subset of $U'\subset U$, $f(U')$ is open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism, $\space f$ must have a continuous inverse $\space f^{-1}: V \to U$. Now we use the fact that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, which means any open subset $W \subset U$ is such that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(W) = f(W) \subset V$ is open, completing the proof.

The notation isn't great, but basically use the "inverse image of an open set is open" definition of continuity to see that the inverse of $f^{-1}$ (which is $f$) produces open images in $V$